# Opacity for colorRGBA lightningchart

Tags: lightningchart

How do we set color with opacity ?

I tried something like `rgba(255, 0, 0, 50);`

even if i change to 100 , there is still opacity ?

What is the range ? for example 0.1 to 1.0 in CSS ,, like that what is the range from low opacity to high opacity in lightningchart ??

Also for please tell the range for colorHEX

```
line.setStrokeStyle(
    new SolidLine({
        thickness: t,
        fillStyle: new SolidFill({
            color: ColorHEX(color).setA(100)
        })
    })
)
```

sometimes even 100 is transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ColorRGBA(r, g, b, a)`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v2.2.0/globals.html#colorrgba) or [`ColorHEX('#RGBA')`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v2.2.0/globals.html#colorhex) to create a `Color` instance with opacity.

```js
const semiTransparentRed = ColorRGBA(255, 0, 0, 125)
const opaqueRed = ColorRGBA(255, 0, 0, 255)
```

[`ColorRGBA`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v2.2.0/globals.html#colorrgba) alpha definition is expecting a number in range 0 - 255. `ColorRGBA(255, 0, 0, 0)` would be fully transparent and `ColorRGBA(255, 0, 0, 255)` would be fully opaque.

You can specify the alpha for [`ColorHEX`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v2.2.0/globals.html#colorhex) by providing it in the color hex code in `#RRGGBBAA` format e.g. `#ff0000aa` where `aa` is the alpha. Other variations of the format are also accepted, `#RGBA`, `0xRRGGBBAA` and `0xRGBA`. The alpha definition is always optional for `ColorHEX`.

All of the color factories return a [`Color`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v2.2.0/classes/color.html) instance. You can edit the transparency of a `Color` instance with [`color.setA`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v2.2.0/classes/color.html#seta) method which expects the value to be in range 0 - 255.

```js
const semiTransparentRed = ColorRGBA(255, 0, 0).setA(125)
```